# Very slow random read/write on HDD

Tags: hard-drive, performance

I have a laptop HDD which is around 8 years old. I feel that the hard disk is very slow, in many cases, I notice the "Active Time" in Windows Task Manager is 100% after logging in and when doing operations like opening an application. I did a benchmark, and here is the result.

[image]

The speed is fine for sequential read which is around 70MB/s, but when going to random R/W, it drops to less than 1MB/s. Is this normal? Or is it due to some component damage/wear and tear?

Hard drive specifications:

```
Western Digital WD5000LPVT 500GB SATA Hard Drive 
Capacity: 500GB.
Speed: 5,400RPM. 
Interface Types: SATA. 
Form Factor: 2.5inx7mm Fits
All laptops. Sector Size: 512 / 512e. 
Sustained Throughput: 147.
Electrical Interface: SATA 300 - 3.0Gbps. 
On-Board Cache: 8MB.
```

[EDIT]: Upload the CrystalDiskInfo result

[image]

Fragmentation (0%)
[image]

Prefetch / Superfetch
[image]

Comment: Don't guess "wear and tear", check disk SMART info and share results.

Comment: Yes it normal - in fact, terrible performance on random-access for HDDs is *the* reason why people spend money on **SSD**s

Comment: Your disk might be fragmented, try running defrag and see what it says. Defragging might turn some non-sequential accesses into sequential ones, making everything faster.

Comment: @MatijaNalis Terrible performance compared to SSDs, sure. But 0.64 MiB/s is fishy even for a HDD. If this weren't a SATA drive, I would suspect a drop to PIO; as is, it's probably a hardware problem. Or _seriously_ fragmented data.

Comment: Is Prefetch/Superfetch active?

Comment: @PTwr Added the SMART info.

Comment: @FabiosaysReinstateMonica It's not fragmented. It shows 0% fragmented.

Comment: @Mast I checked from Registry (Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\PrefetchParameters), for both EnablePrefetcher and EnableSuperfetch has value of 3.

Comment: Well, SMART shows old, but still healthy, disk. "Still" being a keyword. 
(If disk has proper SMART, that is. In past many had crappy/partial implementation)
Poor thing worked 5 hours each day for 8 years, personally I would not trust it much longer.
You feel it to be slow because it was slow, got slower with age, and Windows has no respect for slow HDD's in age of SSD.

Comment: @MatijaNalis I really like how you wrote "spend money on SSDs".  So often, I see, something like "just get an SSD", which ignores the fact they cost a lot of money in relationship to many people's income.   Sure, their prices are coming down, but they are not free like using an existing platter-based hard drive.

Comment: @Luaan _"But 0.64 MiB/s is fishy even for a HDD."_ - No, it's entirely expected. _"Or seriously fragmented data."_ What fragmentation? The benchmark the OP ran does random 4KiB reads. Every block is read from a new random position, straight from disk. What data is on the disk (and how fragmented it is) is irrelevant to the test. And yes, those random reads bring out the worst in spinning disks, hence the abysmal results.

Comment: @rcs:  Check your [reallocated sector count.](https://harddrivegeek.com/reallocated-sector-count/)  Yours looks rather high.  You may want to consider replacing it before it fails - in which case money invested now in an SSD will save you aggravation and lost data later as well as making your laptop faster now.

Comment: @marcelm I missed that it's a laptop drive. 5400 rpm, single platter... ouch.

Comment: In today's news: hard disk are still slow. More at 11.

Comment: @Luaan it is not fishy, it is just the realistic HDD speed. Random [independent benchmark](https://www.storagereview.com/review/western-digital-scorpio-blue-review-500gb-7mm-wd5000lpvt) for that WD models also gives 0.2-0.6MB/s random seek performance.

Comment: @JRE indeed, currently I'm considering an SSD as replacement, to give this old laptop a new lifespan. I am thinking to buy a 500GB SSD and clone this hard drive.

Comment: @JRE You're not reading that correctly.  The reallocated sector count shows 200 on a new drive (of this model).  It counts down when a sector is reallocated.  If it reaches the 140 threshold then the SMART status changes to BAD.  OP has no reallocated sectors.

Comment: Welcome to the past!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

That is perfectly normal for random I/O performance on a 5400 rpm disk. A 5400 rpm disk can manage about 90 IOPS because the required sector will only go under the head 90 times per second (5400 times per minute).

So with 4KB blocks, that is 4KB * 90 = 360KB/s.

This is broadly in line with what you are seeing.

Comment: So it's possible that up/downloading data to the Internet can actually be faster than a local HDD? That's pretty annoying.

Comment: For random I/O in 4KB chunks downloading to the internet will typically be even slower. 90 IOPS is ~ 11ms per operation. Ping time to an internet storage server is typically going to be 2-3x higher than that on a broadband connection.

Comment: @GordanBobic you don't have to wait for a ping time per block.

Comment: @user253751 you do at queue depth 1.

Comment: @GordanBobic and why would that happen?

Comment: @user253751 why would the benchmark above test it?

Comment: @GordanBobic the benchmark of "downloading a file from the internet"? It would not force a queue depth of 1 because the people who wrote the OS didn't want to make downloads extremely slow.

Comment: @ThomasWeller You're the first person I meet who is annoyed by having a fast Internet connection!

Comment: @user253751 I think your argument boils down to what is a network's analogy of random read/write. And there will be no analogy without a flaw or two.

Comment: @user253751 The equivalent of a random block write is a random request to a server, and that means latency of the round-trip between the client and the server (at best, if a connection is already established, and it takes a single round-trip for the request). It will take at least as much time as a ping. You wouldn't have to wait for the round-trip if it were part of a stream (a longer download), which is the equivalent of the sequential performance on a disk.

Comment: @user253751 right, but that would be sequential rather than random access, which the benchmark results above at ~70MB/s So even a slow disk is going to win against cloud storage speed.

Comment: actually unlike on the HDD where the request needs to be finished to be ready to accept the next one (the head needs to move) you can send all the random requests you want to a server in parallel and get the results with a round-trip delay, so the internet is definitely faster

Comment: @jcaron: I disagree: the OS would likely send a lot of commands to the HDD, which could then answer from cache or turn the head. Thus, for a cloud comparison I would send a lot of commands to the Internet server and the responses may be faster than from disk.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: "You're the first person I meet who is annoyed by having a fast Internet connection! " - indeed, I am. I dislike the cloud much and I prefer local storage which is under my control. But if the Cloud starts to be faster than local storage, I have less and less arguments for local storage

Comment: @Eumel this is why HDDs have write caches and why file systems try to organise data in sequential order, which turns some amount of random access into sequential access. Also, to perform the requests in parallel, you have to know in advance the requests you need to make - which is unlikely beyond a certain point for a random access workload.

Comment: *A 5400 rpm disk can manage about 90 IOPS*  That seems optimistic.  You need to account for seek time, too.  IME a 5400 rpm disk will be more likely to be able to do 50-60 IOPS given truly random IO.

Comment: @AndrewHenle, but if it's random, then on average it only has to do half a spin, so don't forget to factor that in as well

Comment: @ThomasWeller you'll hate Dan Luu's [infinite disk article](https://danluu.com/infinite-disk/). Latencies have really changed in recent times.

Comment: @ThomasWeller when downloading games from Steam I am limited by the speed of my (80% full) Intel 660p NVMe drive... this is on a 300 Mbps downlink.

Answer (score 20):

Your HDD is WD5000LPVT, a 2.5" 500GB 5400rpm model.

Looking at [UserBenchmark](https://hdd.userbenchmark.com/SpeedTest/241/WDC-WD5000LPVT-22G33T0) your results are not abnormal. Random read results should be between 0.1-0.5 MB/s, yours are pretty good. UserBenchmark random writes are 0.76-2.3 MB/s, yours ~0.85 is on the low side but not out of range.

These values seem to be normal for this disk model. HDDs usually have terrible random access results, especially 5400rpm ones.

Answer (score 13):

A hard disk drive is made of platters that turn at the specified speed, and read-write heads which move along the radius of the platter.

To read a random block on the disk, two things need to happen:

- The head needs to be moved to the right "track" along the radius of the platter (**seek time**).
- The platter needs to rotate until the right "sector" or block is under the read/write head (**rotational latency**).

Average random seek times are usually somewhere between 9 and 15 ms, depending on the disk. For [this specific disk, it's **12 ms**](https://archive.techarp.com/showarticle6e50.html?artno=755&pgno=2).

Average random rotational latency is directly dependent on drive rotation speed. Disks come in a variety of speeds, from 5400 RPM (revolutions per minute), which is quite standard for the smaller consumer 2.5" disks, up to 15000 RPM for high-end enterprise-grade disks.

At 5400 RPM (which means 90 revolutions per second), it takes on average **5.6 ms** for the right block to be under the read-write head.

That means that on average, reading a random block will take **17.6 ms** (not counting command processing and the data transfer itself, but that's usually peanuts in comparison).

Which in turn means a bit under **57 reads per second**. With **4K blocks** as used by the benchmark, that's 228 KB/s, or **0.228 MB/s**. So the results of the benchmark are actually slightly better than theory!

That's for the `RND4K Q1T1` read test (bottom left of your first screenshot), which is the ultimate random read test, with each read waiting for its results before getting to the next one.

The `Q32T1` test leverages queuing: multiple read commands (up to 32) are sent to the drive before waiting for the results (and as soon as a result comes back, a new read is requested, maintaining a queue of 32 pending reads).

This enables the drive to reorder the reads so they're less random. For instance, the seek time is shorter when going from track 1 to track 2 than from the first to the last, so ordering the reads on increasing tracks saves time. It also helps if several blocks are read from the same track (no seeking, and you can read the first block coming under the read/write head).

The write tests are usually flawed, because disks will cache writes and say "yes yes I got it" even if it's not been written to disk yet, so they're a lot more difficult to judge accurately.

So:

- **Your disk seems to operate within specs**
- **Your disk, like all consumer-grade laptop HDDs, is slow. No surprise here.**
- **If you want better seek (random) performance, nothing beats an SSD.**

Comment: Point # 3 I feel is the true answer to this post. Time to buy an SSD. :-)